# Zipping specific files within a folder - not finding zip file

Tags: python, zip

I've got some code that will write specific extension files within a folder to a zip file. Though I continue to run into an error. I've pulled this code from a few different sources. Could I get some help?

```
ext = [".shp", ".shx", ".prj", ".cpg", ".dbf"]
# compress shapefile and name it the ortho name
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk('D:/combined_shape'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(tuple(ext)):
            zipfile.ZipFile('D:/combined_shape/' + 'compiled' + '/.zip', 'w').write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                               os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file),
                                               'D:/combined_shape/'), compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/Augmentation/merge_shp.py", line 30, in <module>
    zipfile.ZipFile('D:/combined_shape/' + 'compiled' + '/.zip', 'w').write(os.path.join(folder, file),
  File "D:\PyCharmEnvironments\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/combined_shape/compiled/.zip'
```

**EDITS**
[image: Directory]
[image: Zip Directory]

Comment: You don't have the `compiled` subdirectory. And you also left out the filename part of the zip file. If you meant it to be `compiled.zip`, it's a typo: you shouldn't have `/` before `.zip`

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using string concatenation when all the strings are literals? Just write `D:/combined_shape/compiled.zip`

Comment: @Barmar Yes that did fix it. I had concatenating strings because the `compiled` string used to be a variable that I was pulling from another script. I know this isn't part of the question, but not all the files are being zipped. Only the `.shx` is being zipped. Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, it looks like it should zip files with any of the extensions in your list.

Comment: Try adding: `else: print(f'Not zipping {folder}/{file}')` to see what it's skipping.

Comment: @Barmar I do have a few other `.zip` files within that directory, and those print out. But the `.shp`, `.prj`, `.cpg`, and `.dbf` do not print, but are also not in the new zip folder.

Comment: @Barmar I added a couple of images to show you for clarification.

Comment: Try adding `print(folder, files)` at the top of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar added that after the first `for` loop. It prints out everything that you can see in the first image.

Comment: Could it be that the `.shx` file is the last file in the `walk` method and therefore the only one being zipped?

Comment: Open the zip fie once before the loop, and add to it inside the loop. Or use `a` mode to add to the file. `w` mode truncates the file each time through the loop.

Comment: It says it right in the documentation: **The mode parameter should be 'r' to read an existing file, 'w' to truncate and write a new file, 'a' to append to an existing file,**

Comment: Yes, I just changed the `w` to `a` and that worked. Appreciate the help. If you could please post your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "File or directory not found" error is because of `/.zip` in the name of the zip file. The `/` should be removed.

The problem with only getting one file in the archive is the use of `w` mode when opening the `ZipFile`. As it states in the documentation:

> 'w' to truncate and write a new file

So for each file you want to add it's first removing all the files that were added previously.

Open the file once before the loop, then add each file to it.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('D:/combined_shape/compiled.zip', 'w') as z:
    for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk('D:/combined_shape'):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(tuple(ext)):
                z.write(os.path.join(folder, file),
                        os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder, file),
                                        'D:/combined_shape/'), 
                        compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```